# How to handle notification data payload while app is in background?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Here is my MyFirebaseMessagingService.class

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
public MyFirebaseMessagingService() { }
DataBaseUtil dataBaseUtil = null;

String sname;
Intent intent= new Intent();
String orderId;
String strmessage,strmsgtext;

@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    dataBaseUtil = new DataBaseUtil();
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        L.e( "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        RemoteMessage.Notification fcm = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        PojoNotification pojo = new PojoNotification();
        pojo.setTitle(fcm.getTitle());
        pojo.setContent(fcm.getBody());

       Map<String, String> dataMap = remoteMessage.getData();            

       orderId = dataMap.get("orderId").toString().trim();
       sname = dataMap.get("screen_name").toString().trim();
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }
        pojo.setId(new Random().nextInt(9000));
        dataBaseUtil.insertNotification(pojo);
        if (SP.getBoolean(SP.LOGIN) ){
            showNotification(pojo);
        }
        else {
        }
    }else {
        L.e( "Message Notification Body: " + "abcv");

    }
}
```

And here is my showNotification method:

```
 void showNotification(PojoNotification pojo) {

    intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
   intent.putExtra("screen_name", sname);
 //  intent.putExtra(Constance.id,pojo.getId());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("default",
                "SGrip",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription("YOUR_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DISCRIPTION");
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "default")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher) // notification icon

            .setContentTitle(pojo.getTitle()) // title for notification
            .setContentText(pojo.getContent())// message for notification
          //  .setSound(alarmSound) // set alarm sound for notification

            .setAutoCancel(true); // clear notification after click

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pi);
    mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());


}
```

Here i am getting all the notification background and foreground but the problem i am facing is that when my app is in background the data payload data is not fetching and when my app is foreground all data are getting as required

Here, my launcher activity were i get intent extra

```
   if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
```

and here is the notification code server side

```
    {
 "registration_ids" : ["cFxiduH5j9I:APA91bEFAYPOR57yDga8urRuhmPuj_CI9h-bIyEwCcQeyFsvnFU_Nh9zkTmQVE7oiwdXchvIIz4DmUW1nqIOslBg_3oV7cWDZBjwb7WFqQ3E4RZ2T2vXCFN6IQ_1pBIfL67pHwthEZA4"],
 "notification" : {
     "title" : "First Notification",
     "text": "Collapsing A",
     "sound":"default"
 },
 "data" : {
     "screen_name" : "acc_screen"
 }
}
```

I read many tutorials many stackoverflow Q&A but nothing helping me out. i know the same type of questions are many but am not getting the solution from there so i posted the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your app is in background, intent caught in Launcher activity.

I implemented the same in Kotlin, please refer:

```
 val bundle = intent.extras
    if (bundle != null) {
        val notificationModel = NotificationModel()
        try {
            val target = Target()
            if (bundle.containsKey("view"))
                target.view = bundle.getString("view")
            if (bundle.containsKey("circle_id"))
                target.circleId = bundle.getString("circle_id")
            if (bundle.containsKey("user_id"))
                target.userId = bundle.getString("user_id")
            if (bundle.containsKey("group_id"))
                target.groupId = bundle.getString("group_id")
            if (bundle.containsKey("file_id"))
                target.fileId = bundle.getString("file_id")

            notificationModel.target = target
        } catch (ex: JSONException) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

***Updated***

When your app is in background and click on your notification your default launcher will be launched. To launch your desired activity you need to specify click_action in your notification payload.

```
$noti = array
(
'icon' => 'new',
'title' => 'title',
'body' => 'new msg',
'click_action' => 'your activity name comes here'
);
```

And in your `android.manifest` file

Add the following code where you registered your activity

```
 <activity
            android:name="your activity name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="your activity name" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
           </intent-filter>
```

Comment: okay thanks for the help can you please let me know that if i want to open particular activity from this intent extra is it possible ?

Comment: suppose i want to open Activity1 then should i paste above code in manifest in Launcher Activity or in Activity1?

Comment: if i want to open more then 1 activity from click action is it possible to put intent filter in every activity? or is it good coding?

Comment: i want to perform without using click action

Comment: No it will open only one activity, where you defined the Action. And you can do one thing, differentiate click action in notification as well as in Manifest also. So when ever action1 matches, it will jump to acitivty1 and so on for action2 & activity2.